# Scala 2.11 and jsr-223 not working

Tags: scala, jsr223

I am very interested at using the Scala script engine that we have now in scala 2.11

I saw that within the REPL everything works but if I do it from a test (I tried from sbt and maven) then the ScriptEngine for scala is not found.

I tried that to see which ScriptEngine are present

```
println("manager:" + manager.getEngineFactories.size())
manager.getEngineFactories.toList.foreach(factory => println(factory.getClass.getSimpleName))
```

But I only get NashornScriptEngine (I have JDK8)

Does anybody have an idea why I can't find it? I had previously issues with NashornScript in SBT that could be resolved by added fork in Test but this is not the issue here.

It is as if the ScriptEngine is not present in the classpath when you are outside the REPL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you add the REPL (and, maybe, the compiler?) to the classpath? I imagine that if you don't specify the dependency and bring only the library, it would definitely not work.

If you did do that, perhaps if you could be more forthcoming with details on how you are doing this test?

Comment: You are probably right. My question is then what should I add to the classpath? I haven't seen any "REPL lib" in either the doc nor the maven repository. I tried library-all but it didn't work

Comment: Daniel is correct, and the classes you need are in the scala-compiler jar.

Comment: Ok so I have to include scala-compiler in my project. Let me try that and I come back

Comment: Great! yes you have to add ,"org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.11.0" as a dependency and then it works. It makes total sense but they should be clearer in their doc! I hope this will help ppl with this similar issue

Comment: Yes, the tool script adds the libs for you.  But there are bugs in the first cut of the jsr223 support, FYI. Or does that go without saying?